# Media query not working on mobile breakpoint

Tags: html, css, media-queries, breakpoints

I am working on a site for a school project where I have 2 media query breakpoints cascading down from desktop to tablet and finally to mobile. My tablet breakpoint at **991px** is working fine, but my mobile breakpoint at **479px** does not register any changes at all. And I really have no idea what is wrong.

I tried to make more than one breakpoint for my website using media query, expecting it to work right away. The result show that only the media query with the highest `max-width` value works.

Any help is much appreciated.

This is how I have been writing my media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

This is all the code that I have been writing for my media queries if needed

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    width: 96%;
  }
  h2 {
    font-family: 'salomeitalic';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: clamp(50px, 5.208vw, 100px);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #242325;
  }
  .p2 {
    font-family: 'Satoshi-Variable';
    font-weight: medium;
    font-size: clamp(16px, 1.094vw, 21px);
    color: #242325;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-front {
    position: sticky;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: none;
    padding: clamp(20px, 2.083vw, 40px);
  }
  .top-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #242325;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  .nav-logo {
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .nav-top {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  a {
    font-family: 'Satoshi-Variable';
    font-weight: medium;
    font-size: clamp(18px, 1.302vw, 25px);
    color: #FFF8F2;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #242325;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  .contact-wrapper {
    display: none;
  }
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
  }
  .profile-img-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .about-wrapper {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .scroll-button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    width: 104%
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .project-1 {
    height: 455px;
  }
  .project-3 {
    height: 455px;
  }
  .project-5 {
    height: 455px;
  }
  .contact-div {
    height: 435px;
  }
  .arrow-up-left {
    margin-bottom: 17%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  body {
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  h2 {
    font-family: 'salomeitalic';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: clamp(50px, 13.021vw, 250px);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #242325;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%
  }
  .header-left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```
<html lang="da" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML CODE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="projekt-3.css">
</head>
<body>
    
        <nav class="nav-front">
            <div class="top-wrapper">
                    <img class="nav-logo" 
src="exports/logo.svg" alt="Staugaard Design Logo">
                <div class="nav-links">
                    <div class="nav-top">
                        <p>navigation</p>
                        <img class="arrow-down" src="exports/arrow-down.svg">
                    </div>
                    <a href="projekt-3.html">om mig</a>
                    <a href="projekt-3.html">projekter</a>
                    <a href="projekt-3-kontakt.html">kontakt</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-wrapper">
                <div class="margin-buttom">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/staugaard_design/">instagram</a>
                </div>
                <p>©2022</p>
                <a href="projekt-3-kontakt.html"><button>KONTAKT</button></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
   
    <header>
        <div class="header-left">
            <div class="margin">
                <h2>KREATIV DESIGNER & UDVIKLER</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="moving-text-wrapper">
                <img class='orange-star' src="exports/star-orange.svg">
                <p class="white">2022 PORTFOLIO</p>
                <img class='orange-star' src="exports/star-orange.svg">
                <p class="white">2022 PORTFOLIO</p>
                <img class='orange-star' src="exports/star-orange.svg">
            </div>

            <div class="profile-img-wrapper">
            </div>
        </div>

       
        <div class="header-right">
            <div class="about-wrapper">
                <img class="black-star" src="exports/star-2.svg">
                
                <p>hej! mit navn er kristoffer. jeg er en freelance web designer samt web udvikler som bor i odense. Jeg skaber smukke hjemmesider i samarbejde med virksomheder og selvstændige som gerne vil skille sig ud fra konkurrenterne.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-button-wrapper">
                <div class="scroll-button">
                    <img class="orange-arrow" src="exports/orange-arrow.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

   <div class="transition">
        <h1>UDVALGTE<br>PROJEKTER</h1>
   </div>

   <main>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="project-1">
            <div class="project-text1">
                <div class="margin-buttom">
                    <h2>classic curry</h2>
                </div>
                <p class="p2">restauranten classic curry er en klassisk indisk restaurant som laver autentiske retter. projekt gik ud på at vi skulle vælge en hjemmeside som vi synes manglede en kærlig hånd.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="project-visual">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="project-img" src="exports/classic-img.png" alt="classic curry hjemmeside">
                </div>
                <img class="arrow-up-left" src="exports/arrow-up.svg" alt="knap til at se hjemmesiden">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project-2">
            <div class="project-text2">
                <div class="margin-buttom">
                    <h2>gluds</h2>
                </div>
                <p class="p2">gluds café manglede en hjemmeside som kunne fremvise alt hvad caféen har at byde på, i et elegant design.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="project-visual">
                <img class="arrow-up-right" src="exports/arrow-up.svg" alt="knap til at se hjemmesiden">
                <img class="project-img" src="exports/gluds-img.png" alt="gluds cafe hjemmeside">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="contact-div">
            <img class="arrow-up-white" src="exports/arrow-up-white.svg">
            <div class="contact-text">
                <h3>kontakt<br>kontakt<br>kontakt</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project-3">
            <div class="project-text3">
                <div class="margin-buttom">
                    <h2>justesen artpack</h2>
                </div>
                <p class="p2">virksomheden justesen artpack er et kunst transport- og vedligeholdelses firma. De havde brug for en mere advanceret hjemmeside og et mere moderne design, som de selv kunne opdatere med blog indlæg.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="project-visual">
                <div class="img-wrapper">                
                    <img class="project-img" src="exports/justesen-img.png" alt="justesen artpacks hjemmeside">
                </div>
                <img class="arrow-up-left2" src="exports/arrow-up.svg" alt="knap til at se hjemmesiden">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="project-4">
                <div class="project-text4">
                    <div class="margin-buttom">
                        <h2>m/k aps</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p2">m/k service aps er et rengørings firma som manglede et nyere og moderne design, med mere funktionalitet.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="project-visual">
                    <img class="arrow-up-right" src="exports/arrow-up.svg" alt="knap til at se hjemmesiden">
                    <img class="project-img" src="exports/mk-img.png" alt="mk serverice hjemmeside">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-5">
                <div class="project-text5">
                    <div class="margin-buttom">
                        <h2>by gitte lage</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p2">wellness -by gitte lage er en virksomhed som tilbyder wellness behandlinger og massager. i et tæt samarbejde med ejeren hjalp jeg med at bygge virksomhedens online struktur fra bunden.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="project-visual">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="project-img" src="exports/wellness-img.png" alt="mk serverice hjemmeside">
                    </div>
                    <img class="arrow-up-left" src="exports/arrow-up.svg" alt="knap til at se hjemmesiden">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Quick tip: best way to set up your CSS is to start _mobile first_. That way your declarations won't bite each other.

Comment: I know that now, but what would i have to do to work the other way around its too late for me to start over and do it the right way now

Comment: you should write main intial css code and then add some quieries on that

Comment: im not sure what you mean could you elabortate?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to keep the mobile screen media query above the tablet media query code once

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML code also.

Comment: Yes just added it, i appreciate you taking a look at it, if you need the rest of my css aswell just say so. Because right now i only show the css used on media queries

Comment: "(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 991px)" , please use this instead of this "only screen and (max-width: 991px) "

Comment: doesnt work unfortunately